# When someone says to "(only) test the public api", what exactly do they mean by "public api"?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

For example, given a gui application, like a word processor, is the public api the gui itself? Does testing the public api then mean writing tests that start the application and manipulate the mouse and keyboard to press buttons? I assume you are not expected to parse the gui display itself to test expected results, like a user real user would.

The public api for a library seems a bit more straightforward. I assume it is the functions and classes that are accessible when the library is imported into another project.

What about a library written in a functional paradigm? Procedural? Object oriented? What about languages without explicit public and private division.

In essence: can the term "public api" be described in a language, paradigm, and application independent way, with minimal jargon? Examples could be helpful.

Comment: API stands for "Application programming interface", so clearly this is a programming interface not GUI.

Comment: You can think public API is a contract(methods, types) which consumer of this library can access.

Answer (score 0):

*"given a gui application, like a word processor, is the public api the gui itself?"*. No - the problem you're having is that you're looking at the 'big picture', without considering the scope of what unit testing is.

The StackOverflow tag defines it as: *"**Unit testing** is a method by which individual units of source code are tested to determine if they are fit for use"*. From that perspective, the expression makes sense, because you are testing each individual class. If there is a good separation of concerns, most of those classes won't even realise that they are part of the "Word Processor".

The idea is that you should be testing that class solely based on how other classes *see* that class, without looking into the private implementation of that class.

For example, when testing a class which holds a collection of things, the tests should **not** be based on the fact that the collection is privately held as an array (or whatever), and that "if I add an item to the collection, then the private array field should contain the item I added". Tests written this way will break if the internal implementation is changed, even though the class may work correctly.

Instead, the tests should be based around "if I add an item to the collection, then (for example) I should be able to get it back by enumerating the collection", since enumeration is likely to be in the public API of that class. Tests written like this should still work if the internal implementation is changed, without changing the *behaviour* of the class.

Note that scope is important when considering the phrase "public API" part of that phrase. When considering a library, you might think that it means you should only test the classes which are publically exposed. Whereas from the scope of looking at each individual class (some of which may not be accessible from outside the library), each of them expose a public API for how other classes should interact with them. This second scope is the one which unit testing relates to. It's not saying that the first scope is bad, it's just that testing the whole library isn't **unit** testing, it's **integration** testing.

Comment: Can you provide some examples for paradigms other than object oriented? Such as how this applies to functional programming.

Comment: I'd see functional programming a bit like dependency injection is in an object-oriented paradigm. You should be testing the thing that you're injecting the function(s) into without giving it the real functions. In an OO paradigm, you'd use mocking to mock the behaviour of the dependencies that are injected, to isolate the testing of the unit. So the function(s) that you're injecting would need to be mocks, rather than concrete implementations (otherwise you're back to integration testing again).